# How to test Xcode Source Editor Extension?

Tags: xcode, xctest

I am writing XCode Source Editor Extension and I would like to add some tests so I can develop faster.

My setup is

```
MyContainerApplication
  - SourceEditorExtension
    - SourceEditorCommand.swift
    - MyClass.swift
```

I would like to test MyClass.swift. MyContainerApplication has target dependency to SourceEditorExtension.

So I create Unit test with MyContainerApplication set as a host application.

In my test I can then call:

```
@testable import MyContainerApplication

class Test: XCTestCase {

    func testSomething() {

         let c = MyClass()
    }
}
```

But XCode says MyClass can't be found, which makes sense because it is not included in the HostApplication but in the SourceEditorExtension. I also can't call

```
@testable import SourceEditorExtension
```

because it's not a module.

And I can't add `MyClass.swift` directly to my test target or host application target because it uses XcodeKit framework. I will get an error:

```
XcodeKit module not found
```

It looks like XcodeKit can't be imported anywhere else than in the SourceEditorExtension, not even in tests.

So my question is - is there some another way to test the Source Editor Extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can check how Unit Tests done here [SwiftInitializerGenerator](https://github.com/Bouke/SwiftInitializerGenerator/blob/master/SwiftInitializerGeneratorTests/SwiftInitializerGeneratorTests.swift). Testable code is shared between two targets. And no @testable inside tests. Try to get rid of any dependence of XcodeKit inside your class. Probably now it is the one way for extension tests

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `MyClass.swift` is set to both `SourceEditorExtension` and `MyContainerApplicationTests`.